# Iterating a list to make API calls

Tags: javascript, beginner, mongodb

I'm new to JavaScript and was hoping there was a cleaner way to write this. It's a block of code that looks at a group of documents in a collection (called Messages), and makes a call to the GitHub API for each one. If any of the API calls finds a certain string in the response, the function returns `true` via callback. If all of the API calls are exhausted without finding the string, the function returns `false`. The only way I could really think to do this was with the async module, which feels like a dirty/ugly solution. I was hoping someone here might be able to show me if/how this could be possible without the async module.

```
function isUserBlacklisted(user, topCallback){
  // Grab each alert we've sent to that user,
  // see if any of their comments are 'STOP'
  var isBlacklisted = false;
  Messages.find({ user: user }).toArray(function(err, messages){
    async.eachSeries(messages, function(message, callback){
      if (isBlacklisted){
        // eachSeries checks each one. This short-circuits the call so we don't
        // waste API calls if we find out the user is blacklisted halfway
        // through the list.
        callback(); 
      }
      else{
        var options = {
          user: message.user,
          repo: message.repo,
          number: message.number
        }
        github.issues.getComments(options, function(err,obj){
          console.log("Made a call to github for issue #" + message.number);
          if(isStopInComments(obj)){
            Messages.update(options, {$set:{isBlacklisted: true}});
            isBlacklisted = true;
          }
          callback();
        });
      }
    },
    function(err){ topCallback(isBlacklisted)});
  });
}
```

Comment: It doesn't look to me like this code would even work.  `isBlackListed` won't be set yet when you try to return it as the return value from `isUserBlackListed()` because it's value comes from async operations that won't complete until later.

Comment: Woops, i forgot to take that last bit out of there. The whole thing works as a callback by calling topCallback once async completes.